# Heroku copy variable to another variable

Tags: laravel, heroku, laravel-8, vuejs3, environment

I have the following variables in my local .env:

```
MIX_APP_URL=http://localhost
MIX_TEST_1=${MIX_APP_URL}
MIX_TEST_2="${MIX_APP_URL}"
MIX_TEST_3=$MIX_APP_URL
```

This gives me the result (it is the result I expect in my deploy):

[image: 1]

In my deployment on Heroku I have the following:

[image: 2]

When I run the command  `heroku config`  I get the following variables:

[image: 3]

And in the deploy I get the following result:

[image: 4]

Comment: The expanding of the .env variables happens via the PHP library that Laravel uses. Heroku probably does not support expanding (from what is seen here at least). Perhaps you can deploy a .env file regardless to have laravel read it

Comment: I think the problem is with heroku. Can you check with them ?